# Access to the current section number inside `DeclareTOCStyleEntry`

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocbasic

I'm using KOMA-Script and I want to show additional information inside the TOC.
Imagine the following code:

```tex
\section{S}
\immediate\write\@auxout{\global\noexpand\@namedef{@info-\arabic{section}}{Cool information}}
```

Now I want to show *"Cool information"* beside the section in my table of contents.
I thought this could be done like this:

```tex
\CloneTOCEntryStyle{tocline}{@tocsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    entryformat={\marginpar{\csname @info-\arabic{<current section number>}\endcsname}},
]{@tocsection}{section}
```

I'm looking for a way to get access to the *current section number* in order to access the previously stored *"Cool information"*.

MWE (https://www.overleaf.com/7456392927dzbtfrpcrrpk):

```tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\CloneTOCEntryStyle{tocline}{@tocsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    entryformat={\marginpar{\csname s@info-1\endcsname}}
]{@tocsection}{section}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@auxout{\global\noexpand\@namedef{s@info-\arabic{section}}{Cool information}}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Line 5 shouldn't contain a hard-coded `1` but the number of the section that is currently formatted.

Comment: don't show only snippets. Always make a small complete document that people can use for tests.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry, I updated my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there is an option, this is actually not passed with the contentsline macro. You could try something like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\CloneTOCEntryStyle{tocline}{@tocsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    entryformat={},
]{@tocsection}{section}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\scr@numberline{\marginpar{\csname s@info-#1\endcsname}}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@auxout{\global\noexpand\@namedef{s@info-\thesection}{Cool information}}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works great. I wasn't aware of the `\scr@numberline` macro. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In the example (and several other cases) this is a very smart solution. So just to note: This does only work as long as the argument to `\scr@numberline` is `\thesection`. KOMA-Script allows to redefine the ToC entry written, by redefining `\sectiontocentry`.